# If I am running Ubuntu off of a USB, can I upgrade to 16.04 directly from that USB?

Tags: 16.04, usb

I've been using 15.10 for quite some time now from a USB, and I kept getting notifications that an upgrade to 16.04 was available.

So I want to upgrade but I'm not sure if I do it from my USB, will it override my windows on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not override, overwrite or affect your Windows on your laptop.

**Explanation:**

Your Usb Drive (a pendrive) is a separate device, i.e. a different drive.  It will be identified to the system as the next available letter, whereas your first and the main drive of your Laptop is your `/dev/sda`.  The next drive specification for your USB drive will be `/dev/sdb`.

You can choose which drive to boot to.  You can also choose or specify which drive for your OS installation.

Since you have already installed Ubuntu 15.10 on your USB drive (which is most likely `/dev/sdb`) an upgrade of that OS installation will be performed on that drive and that drive along.

While running and upgrade your grub, if you specify `/dev/sda` as your boot disk, when you boot your computer from the `/dev/sda` drive, it will boot `Grub` and have both Windows and Ubuntu as a boot option.  This doesn't affect the actual Windows installation.  You can always use a Windows disk to overwrite Grub.